# Filter out Saturdays and Sundays from dataset

Tags: excel

Need help to delete Saturdays and Sundays from an Excel dataset as first
goal. If I can make it, erase holidays too. Rapiminer as favorite method.
Here's what I got so far: could convert timestamp from UNIX to human, but can't imagine how to erase Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: Ok pnuts, thanks a lot for your fast reply n advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to provide some conversion from the UNIX (aka POSIX) timestamp to an Excel Date format. Typically this is performed by dividing the timestamp by 86,400 (number of seconds in a day) and adding 25,569 (number of days from 01-Jan-1900 to 01-Jan-1970). Once Excel has a true date it recognizes, the [NETWORKDAYS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48E717BF-A7A3-495F-969E-5005E3EB18E7) or newer [NETWORKDAYS.INTL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-INTL-function-A9B26239-4F20-46A1-9AB8-4E925BFD5E28) can be used to provide a filtering criteria in a helper column. Using a helper column allows the POSIX timestamp to remain unchanged while you filter the results and supplementing a holidays list is a small matter.

[image: NETWORKDAYS from POSIX]

The formula used in the 'helper' column in d@ is,

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A2/86400+25569, A2/86400+25569, $AA$2:$AA$11)
```

This returns a *0* for weekends and holidays and a *1* for workdays.

The whole process from opening the CSV, populating the holidays and helper column then removing all unwanted and closing the file. can be achieved with some VBA.

```
Sub import_UNIX_Timestamps()
    Dim fp As String, fn As String
    Dim rHOLIDAYs As Range, vHOLIDAYs As Variant, wb As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    fp = Environ("TEMP")
    fn = "long to short ratios.csv"
    vHOLIDAYs = Array(DateSerial(2015, 1, 1), DateSerial(2015, 1, 19), _
                      DateSerial(2015, 2, 16), DateSerial(2015, 5, 25), _
                      DateSerial(2015, 4, 4), DateSerial(2015, 9, 7), _
                      DateSerial(2015, 10, 12), DateSerial(2015, 11, 11), _
                      DateSerial(2015, 11, 26), DateSerial(2015, 12, 25))

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fp & Chr(92) & fn)

    With wb
        With .Worksheets(1)
            .Cells(2, 27).Resize(UBound(vHOLIDAYs) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(vHOLIDAYs)
            Set rHOLIDAYs = .Range("AA2:AA" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 27).End(xlUp).Row)
            With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                .Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 16
                .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "0"
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count + 1)
                    With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, .Columns.Count - 1)
                        .Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(A2/86400+25569, A2/86400+25569, " & rHOLIDAYs.Address & ")"
                        .Value = .Value
                    End With
                    .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=0
                    With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, .Columns.Count - 1)
                        If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then _
                            .EntireRow.Delete
                    End With
                    .AutoFilter field:=4
                    .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).Resize(1, 27).EntireColumn.Delete
                End With
            End With
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        '.Close savechanges:=True
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I've commented out the actual saving and closing of the CSV so that it remains on screen.